# OpenCV vs MATLAB (shape measurement function for image processing)

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, shapes

I need some shape measurement functions for OpenCV. Is there any function that can calculate

entropy,
Solidity,
EulerNumber,
Eccentricity,
AreaOverPerimeter,
Perimeter,
equivalentDiameter,
Filled Area.

These are MATLAB functions. But I want to calculate these properties with OpenCV. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct 'regionprops' style command in OpenCV as far as I my knowledge goes, but you can find some use in using Moments, ArcLengths and Contour Areas. Eccentricity for example can be derived using moments. Please refer here for further documentation on OpenCV shape descriptors.

[OpenCV reference 1](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html)

[OpenCV reference 2](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_properties/py_contour_properties.html)

You can find how to get eccentricity from moments [here](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Vision_lecture/node36.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually i need the functions which can calculate these properties.Is there any code which is moments function that can calculate these properties(euler etc) in opencv?